# Canvas screenshot partially blank for Youtube pages

Tags: canvas, firefox-addon, screenshot

I have a Firefox add-on that takes screenshots of web pages. It works fine, except on Youtube: the player does not show up in the image, it is blank. I have noticed the same problem with all screenshot add-ons for Firefox, except Fireshot.

The screenshot is done by creating an HTML canvas on the page:

```
var canvas = window.document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'canvas');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
canvas.style.width = canvas.style.maxwidth = width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.style.maxheight = height + "px";
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.save();
context.drawWindow(win, 0, 0, width, height, "rgb(255,255,255)");
context.restore();
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

I have tried a couple of things, but they did not make a difference:

- set wmode to opaque
- delay screen capture

Screenshots of other Flash elements on other sites, or even Youtube videos embedded on other sites work fine.

Any idea how to ensure the Youtube player is part of the picture?

Comment: can you post a couple of results of the screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Set wmode to transparent, not opaque.

Comment: Please expand more on your answer.

Comment: In the above, question, it was said " set wmode to opaque ". So I was telling the person to, instead, "set wmode to transparent". This is a clear answer based in the question.